# how did these things end in their climactic location?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the final battle of Avengers: Endgame, Tony Stark manages to steal the Infinity Stones from Thanos’s gauntlet and insert them in his own glove. We don’t see how he pries them loose from Thanos’s gauntlet, but it was done so smoothly that Thanos himself does not see or feel it happening.

We then see the stones hovering over the glove for a moment before they settle into place and give Tony vast power.

What was causing the hovering? Was it the same effect that allowed the stones to the stolen in the first place? Was the glove specially made for holding the stones? If so, when was the plan made for Tony to take the stones and why did they think he would be able to wield them (the point is made earlier that only the Hulk can do so without being destroyed). I thought Scarlett Witch might have been involved, but she had been dead until moments before and there was no chance for Tony to coordinate plans with her. So, basically, how did the stones end up in the glove?

Answer (score 2):

At this point in the movies, Tony's suit is now nano-technology which allows him to control the suit in every way. He just creates the tool he needs for the job when he needs it. What you see is him moving the stones in to place by adjusting the nano-bots in his suit.

For prying out the stones, we saw earlier that it's no that difficult. Thanos thus plucked the power stone directly off the glove to punch Captain Marvel. With Tony's nano-suit, he just had to touch them. The suit would grab the stones, and he'd pull them off when Thanos pushed him away.

Comment: But what about the hovering?

Comment: They're not hovering.  They're embedded in the skin of the suit. The little nano-bots are pushing the stones around.

Comment: I thought we saw them hovering over the surface of the glove before settling into place. No?

Comment: You do see them move. What you're seeing is the stones embedded in the skin of his suit. Tony can move the skin at will, so he's moving them in place.

Comment: They may have been elevated by nano-bots to keep them out of the way while they were moved into place and glove reconfigured itself into suitable receptacles. Or they shrunk to fit the receptacles the glove created (which you can see are much smaller than the gauntlet and the earlier glove).